# How do I programmatically write a shortcut to a specific page on the homescreen of the Android launcher?

Tags: java, android, shortcut, launcher, homescreen

I am currently working on an Android application whereupon I programmatically write a shortcut to the home screen.  Something like this:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
shortcutIntent.setClassName(ai.packageName, ai.name);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appName);

BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable)(res.get(app_id).activityInfo.loadIcon(p).getCurrent());
Bitmap newbit;
newbit=bd.getBitmap();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, newbit);

intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

(it was actually a StackOverflow post that pointed me to this solution).

Anyway, when I run the app in the emulator, the shortcut is written to the fifth page from the left(on 2.3 home screen ).  A subsequent run writes the shortcut to the 4th page from the left on the home screen.

My question is this:  is there a way to write the shortcut to the center page or the first page (like passing indexes for the 2-D array that seems to hold the app shortcuts)? am I missing something in the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot decide where the shortcut will go.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case.  Can you elaborate a bit on your answer?

Comment: There's nothing to elaborate on, Launcher doesn't let you choose where the shortcut will go. There is no API to achieve this.

Comment: Okay.  It seems odd though to allow a shortcut to be created this way and not be able to have finer control as to where it will be written.  I don't the see the utility in it.  Thanks for your answer, though.  I will have to try a different approach.