# Install an application shortcut programmatically

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am looking for a way to install a shortcut to my home `Activity` from inside my application.   I only want to install the shortcut if it isn't there already.  What is the best way to do this?  Can I choose which screen the shortcut gets placed on?

Comment: You can use an intent just like loading any other activity, unless I understand your question wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my research, you can place a shortcut to your `Activity` on the `Homescreen`, but you can't control which screen it shows up on.

Here is a reference for you, it should help you with sending the activity to the homescreen, but you likely won't be able to tell if one is already added, and you can't tell it which screen to place it on.

[How to place a shortcut.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345561/how-do-i-programmatically-write-a-shortcut-to-a-specific-page-on-the-homescreen-o)