# Can i change the Pre-installed application icon from my application

Tags: android, android-widget

Is it possible to create an android app that is able to change pre-installed applications launcher icons.

if yes then please provide links, code that can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saying "Pre-installed", you mean system apps? If it is, then that is not possible, as far as I know from Android

**EDIT:**
Unless the solution that you're looking for is simply changing the shortcut, otherwise the answer is **NO**.

Comment: yes, it can any app that is installed on my phone. But I just saw a link of application on android market that can change application icon.https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.james.IconChangerWidget&hl=en

Comment: Then I'm afraid there's no permanent solution to that. Shortcuts might help though

Comment: If no then how this **app** is doing. [Icon Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.james.IconChangerWidget&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** permanently change their icon but, you can change their icon as providing shortcuts for any application.

You can find any help by considering these post.

- [Android create shortcuts on the home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6337431/593709)
- [Creating shortcuts in Android via Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6424246/593709)
- [Homescreen shortcuts with icons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7754953/593709)
- [How do I programmatically write a shortcut to a specific page on the
  homescreen of the Android launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5345561/593709)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to do this:

- First you install your application on device
- After some time you want to change your application's icon to other icon

---

Simple answer to your question:

### NO WAY

If you want to do this, first answer these questions:

1. If you want to change the icon, you will definitely will keep it inside SD card folder or any other folder from where application will pick the icon. So if any other applications are also storing their icons like this, anyone can change their icons too which is nothing but hacking.
2. If you are changing your icon or any other application components, what is the meaning of [Application Versioning](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html)

Comment: Right,But i am just thinking that may be i can customize my menu screen. And can change the application's icon (only Launcher icon) through my own application.

Comment: If no then how this **app** is doing. [Icon Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.james.IconChangerWidget&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

what did you mean by "change pre-installed applications launcher icons" 
Do you mean to change the android icon and replace with your own icon? If so, the answer is yes. You can just replace your icon into the drawable folder of your current workspace. The name of your icon should with the name "icon.png or icon.jpg or icon.gif"

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit any system (pre - installed) App properties in Android Phone.