# add android launcher shortcut to home screen

Tags: java, android, shortcut, launcher, homescreen

[This person was generous enough to add his code to his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345561/how-do-i-programmatically-write-a-shortcut-to-a-specific-page-on-the-homescreen). But I can't make out where to get the following variables:

`res`, `app_id`, and `p` in

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) (res.get(app_id).activityInfo.loadIcon(p).getCurrent());
```

Here is his code:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
shortcutIntent.setClassName(ai.packageName, ai.name);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appName);

BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable)(res.get(app_id).activityInfo.loadIcon(p).getCurrent());
Bitmap newbit;
newbit=bd.getBitmap();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, newbit);

intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Also, are there anything that I must add to the manifest file?

EDIT:

I replace

```
BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable)(res.get(app_id).activityInfo.loadIcon(p).getCurrent());
Bitmap newbit;
newbit=bd.getBitmap();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, newbit);
```

with

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
        Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.launcher_icon));
```

and it still does not work. Which is why I am wondering about the manifest file.

Comment: Read the documentation for the called functions. There is described what these parameters mean.

Comment: It seems that you didn't made any effort to understand and modify the code yourself

Comment: @MichaelButscher do you know why my new code is not working? Is there something to add in the manifest?

Comment: You should be more precise what "is not working" means. Does it compile? If so, what happens when you run it, which error messages appear? In the manifest you need `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />` but this may not be your only problem

Comment: @MichaelButscher that's all that was missing. Thanks! Do you mind reposting as a response so I may accept it? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manifest you need

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Comment: Every time I launch the app it creates an additional shortcut. Is there a way to specify that only one shortcut be created?

Comment: You must place the code in an appropriate menu handling function or into a button listener